# SQL totals pr group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the sum of sales "within last 6 weeks" pr week.
That is from today i need:

- Sum of sales 1 week back from today.
- Sum of sales 2 weeks back from today.
- Sum of sales 3 weeks back from today.
- ... Until 6 weeks back.

I have the following query:

```
select retailerid,stylenumber,size,length,
    case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-1,GETDATE()) then SUM(quantity) else 0 end as w_1,
    case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-2,GETDATE()) then SUM(quantity) else 0 end as w_2,
    case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-3,GETDATE()) then SUM(quantity) else 0 end as w_3,
    case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-4,GETDATE()) then SUM(quantity) else 0 end as w_4,
    case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-5,GETDATE()) then SUM(quantity) else 0 end as w_5,
    case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-6,GETDATE()) then SUM(quantity) else 0 end as w_6        
    from someSalesTable
    left join dimdate on datekey = fk_date
    group by retailerid,stylenumber,size,length
```

Error is that 'date' is not in a grouping clause, but how to fix that?

The easy (but ugly) fix is to make 6 different queries :/, but I need this information in one result, since its to be joined with another CTE.

Comment: Your query calculates cumulative sums.  Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should `SUM()` the entire `CASE WHEN` expression and not just the `quantity`

```
select retailerid,stylenumber,size,length,
    SUM(case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-1,GETDATE()) then (quantity) else 0 end) as w_1,
    SUM(case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-2,GETDATE()) then (quantity) else 0 end) as w_2,
    SUM(case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-3,GETDATE()) then (quantity) else 0 end) as w_3,
    SUM(case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-4,GETDATE()) then (quantity) else 0 end) as w_4,
    SUM(case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-5,GETDATE()) then (quantity) else 0 end) as w_5,
    SUM(case when date > dateadd(WEEK,-6,GETDATE()) then (quantity) else 0 end) as w_6        
    from someSalesTable
    left join dimdate on datekey = fk_date
    group by retailerid,stylenumber,size,length
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date column should be in aggregate function if you have a condition while using `GROUP BY` clause :

```
select retailerid, stylenumber, size, length,
       sum(case when [date] > dateadd(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()) then quantity else 0 end) as w_1,
       . . .
from someSalesTable left join 
     dimdate 
     on datekey = fk_date
group by retailerid, stylenumber, size, length;
```